# Send content of Google Sheet with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to create a script that'll send me the content of a google sheet by email on a weekly basis.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: It needs to be in the in the Body

Comment: https://mailparser.io/blog/send-emails-from-google-spreadsheet/

Answer (score 0):

This will send the sheet as a xls to your email. Get this to work then set a time based trigger. - also notice this is a private sheet, that gets set public for a brief moment while it emails and then sets back to private.

```js
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
  
  try {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
    
    // sets sharing to public - to send out email.
    sheet.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + ss.getId() + "/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&key=" + "YOUR_KEY_GOES_HERE";
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    
    Logger.log(url);
    
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
    
    var now = new Date();
    
    MailApp.sendEmail("YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE", "Backup " + now , "Backup " + now , {attachments: [blob]});
    
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
    // returns the file back to Private access
    sheet.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @OblongMedulla, I should have been clearer - it needs to be in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution so far but it's not clean & far from ideal:

```html
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = range.getValues();
  var body = '';
  for( var row in data ) {
    for( var col in data[row] ) {
        body += data[row][col] + '\t';
      }
    }
    body += '\n';
  }
  Logger.log(body);
  // MailApp.sendEmail('your@email.com', 'Director Dealings', body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) on how to send emails from a Spreadsheet.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

You need to use the [`MailApp.sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)). Just be noted that there are four versions of this method